# Local Variable has Value 0 Pass By Reference

Tags: c++

My heap is based on my DynamicArray (ArrayList), and the DynamicArray adds/removes from the list by taking references of elements.

My problem is with a function called fixIndexes. It is supposed to fix the indexes in the array when an element is added in the heap. The function works perfectly except for the last element is zero. I think it has to do with the local variable being popped off the stack after it is added to the array.

I'm curious to know why this is the only variable that is 0, and maybe a better approach or solution.

DynamicArray signatures:

```
bool add(T& element);
void set(uint index, T& value);
T& remove(uint index);
uint getSize();
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../DynamicArray/DynamicArray.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace triforce;

DynamicArray<int> array;

void fixIndexes(uint start, int& elemToSet)
{
    if(start >= array.getSize())
    {   
        cout << "Start: " << start << " elemToSet: " << elemToSet << "\n";
        int temp = elemToSet;
        cout << "Temp: " << temp << "\n";
        array.add(temp);
    }   
    else
    {   
        cout << "Start: " << start << " elemToSet: " << elemToSet << "\n";
        int temp = array.get(start);
        array.set(start, elemToSet);
        fixIndexes((start * 2) + 1, temp);
    }   

}

int main()
{
    int val0 = 1;
    int val1 = 2;
    int val2 = 3;
    int val3 = 4;
    int val4 = 5;
    int val5 = 6;
    int val6 = 7;
    int val7 = 8;
    int val8 = 9;
    int val9 = 10; 
    int val10 = 11; 
    int val11 = 12; 
    int val12 = 13; 
    int val13 = 14; 
    int val14 = 15; 

    int val15 = 2;

    array.add(val0);
    array.add(val1);
    array.add(val2);
    array.add(val3);
    array.add(val4);
    array.add(val5);
    array.add(val6);
    array.add(val7);
    array.add(val8);
    array.add(val9);
    array.add(val10);
    array.add(val11);
    array.add(val12);
    array.add(val13);
    array.add(val14);
    cout << array.toString() << "\n";

    fixIndexes(1, val15);
    cout << array.toString() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

Start: 1 elemToSet: 2
Start: 3 elemToSet: 2
Start: 7 elemToSet: 4
Start: 15 elemToSet: 8
Temp: 8
[1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 0]
```

Comment: you know that arrays in C++ start from 0, right? :)

Comment: If you think the implementation of `array.add()` isn't relevant to this, think again. You report you're "adding" `8` after overwriting its slot with `4`, then you `array.add(temp)` with `temp` as `8`, yet it appears nowhere in your array object list. Further, `temp` isn't even needed in the top if-block. `array.add(elemToSet)` should be sufficient.

Comment: Also the fact that the method gets int&, ie it's recursively changing the variables outside, can be a problem

Comment: Yes I know they start from 0. I wanted to start at index 1 because that's where the new value should be added. Ya I have temp in there just because I was messing around with some different options.

Hm, I will mess with it a bit more. Do you need me to post the code for add?

Comment: Sorry to double post, but when I get rid of temp and use elemToSet directly I get the value 32767 instead of 0 for the last slot.